# TFS connection errors - But Server/Database is Up

Tags: .net, sql-server, version-control, tfs

For some reason, I've been unable to connect to TFS once a day for about 20 or so minutes.  The TFS server is up and SQL Server is up and running, but TFS cannot be connected to.  When I remote into the TFS server, I can load up TFS management, but it hangs when it tries to connect to the server.

The errors I see in the event log are related to the TFSJobAgent not being able to sync certain identities, and they are mostly system/admin accounts listed.  Could this be the reason?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programmatic issue, but a deployment/system setup issue. It probably belongs on ServerFault

Comment: You can try stopping the TfsJobAgent when this occurs to see if TFS is back up. I doubt it's related though. What are the CPU/Memory usages of TFS (TfsJobAgent, w3wp processes) when this problem occurs?

Comment: I restarted that service and it stopped/started fine.  CPU/Memory is normal (it's happening right now).  It's not showing any network traffic on the local area connection.  I can go to IE and browse somewhere...

Comment: OK this seems like it would be the error: TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Verify that the server that is hosting the database is operational, and that network problems are not blocking communication with the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was very odd... I restarted the server, that didn't fix it.  But about an hour later, a co-worker reset IIS, and then it worked fine.... weird...